# Data warehouse dimensional model Disadvantages

Tags: data-warehouse

I tried allot to find answer for disadvantages of dimensional model but couldn't found any.

Can someone help me in a short paragraph or bullet points, what are the disadvantages of dimensional model in data warehouse?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

What is the purpose of this? Isn't it like asking disadvantages of having an engine or a transmission in a car?

Comment: It’s a tutorial question to research from internet but I couldn’t found any that’s why I am asking here.

Comment: I bet you can find any. Data ware houses are built on dimensional models. If you take dimensional model out of a data warehouse, all you have is a database.